# Simple dereferencing pointer issue in C++

Tags: c++

Im using `qt4` and embedding a webkit view in it. The webkit object expects a `QUrl` object containint the url. My code looks like this:

```
QUrl *application = new QUrl();

if (argc < 2) {
  application->setUrl(DEFAULT_PAGE);
}
else {
  application->setUrl(argv[2]);
}
view->load(application);
view->show();
```

But `view->load(application);` fails here, as `view->load` expects a `(const QUrl&)` and I'm passing a `(QUrl*&)`

I dereferenced the application object like this:

```
view->load(&application);
```

But that cnoverted `application` to `(QUrl**)`

How can I convert `application` to `(const QUrl&)`?

Comment: `&obj` is **not** dereferencing anything.

Comment: I think you meant `*application`, not `&application`...

Comment: `&obj` takes the address of `obj`. Compare this with `*obj` which dereferences a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
view->load(*application);
```

See [dereference operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator).